# Remove "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <10.95> not available "

Tags: fonts, fontsize, warnings

I use package stix2. The document can be compiled, but those warnings keep annoying me. Is there any way they can be removed?

I copy them here:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <10.95> not available Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 31
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <8> not available Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 31
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <6> not available Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 31
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <10.95> not available
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <8> not available Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 3
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <6> not available Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 3
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <10.95> not available
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <8> not available Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 3
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <6> not available Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 3
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <10.95> not available Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 31
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <8> not available Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 31
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <6> not available Font shape `LS2/stix2
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I've fixed your code formatting and adjusted the tags.  It'd be easier to help you with your problem if you could show us a minimal working example that has these problems.  At the moment, something strange is happening on lines 3 and 31.  What you are doing there?

Comment: not much you can do here. The font substituations are declared so that there not silent. That is a design decision of the package author.

Answer (score 3):

The annoying warnings are issued when `\boldmath` or `\bm` is used. Redeclare the needed font families to use `ssub` instead of `sub`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}

\DeclareFontFamily{LS1}{stix2bb}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathbb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{m}{it}{<-> stix2-mathbbit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{b}{n} {<->ssub * stix2bb/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{b}{it}{<->ssub * stix2bb/m/it}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{LS2}{stix2ex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2ex}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2ex}{b}{n} {<->ssub * stix2ex/m/n}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{LS2}{stix2cal}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2cal}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathcal}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2cal}{b}{n} {<->ssub * stix2cal/m/n}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{LS2}{stix2tt}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2tt}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stix2tt}{b}{n} {<->ssub * stix2tt/m/n}{}

\begin{document}

\boldmath $x=y$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `sub` (substitute) size function to act like `ssub` (silent substitute) size function and just write to the log file, not the terminal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSizeFunction{sub}{\sub@sfcnt\@font@info}
\makeatother
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
\boldmath
$\mathcal{x} \mathbb{x}$
\end{document}
```